Convert a list of dictionaries to a dictionary of dictionaries or another list of dictionaries
I have this list of dictionaries:
repolist:
  - org: rhosp-rhel8
    registry: registry.redhat.io
    repo: openstack-zaqar-base
  - org: rhosp-rhel8
    registry: registry.redhat.io
    repo: openstack-zaqar-wsgi
  - org: rhceph
    registry: registry.redhat.io
    repo: rhceph-4-dashboard-rhel8

I want to convert it to this:
repolist:
  - org: rhosp-rhel8
    repos: 
        - name: openstack-zaqar-base
          registry: registry.redhat.io
        - name: openstack-zaqar-wsgi
          registry: registry.redhat.io
  - org: rhceph
    repos: 
      - name: rhceph-4-dashboard-rhel8
        registry: registry.redhat.io

, or this:
 
repolist:
  rhosp-rhel8:
    - name: openstack-zaqar-base
      registry: registry.redhat.io
    - name: openstack-zaqar-wsgi
       registry: registry.redhat.io
  rhceph:
    - name: rhceph-4-dashboard-rhel8
      registry: registry.redhat.io


Your question is incomplete. Do you want to do it programmatically or are you having a problem with YAML's syntax?

@RojanGh. I’d say with Ansible since set_fact is an Ansible module and the question in tagged accordingly.

Apologies, yes, with Ansible.
I don't really care if it's a series of filters or just a Jinja loop (which I failed to make it work)

The simplest option
  result: "{{ dict(repolist|groupby('org')) }}"

gives
  result:
    rhceph:
    - org: rhceph
      registry: registry.redhat.io
      repo: rhceph-4-dashboard-rhel8
    rhosp-rhel8:
    - org: rhosp-rhel8
      registry: registry.redhat.io
      repo: openstack-zaqar-base
    - org: rhosp-rhel8
      registry: registry.redhat.io
      repo: openstack-zaqar-wsgi

Optionally, create a list
  result: "{{ dict(repolist|groupby('org')) |
              dict2items(key_name='org', value_name='repos') }}"

gives
  result:
  - org: rhceph
    repos:
    - org: rhceph
      registry: registry.redhat.io
      repo: rhceph-4-dashboard-rhel8
  - org: rhosp-rhel8
    repos:
    - org: rhosp-rhel8
      registry: registry.redhat.io
      repo: openstack-zaqar-base
    - org: rhosp-rhel8
      registry: registry.redhat.io
      repo: openstack-zaqar-wsgi

Use the filter ansible.utils.remove_keys if you have to get rid of the attribute org
  r_groups: "{{ repolist | groupby('org') }}"
  r_keys: "{{ r_groups | map('first') }}"
  r_vals: "{{ r_groups | map('last') |
              ansible.utils.remove_keys(target=['org']) }}"
  result: "{{ dict(r_keys|zip(r_vals)) }}"

gives
  result:
    rhceph:
    - registry: registry.redhat.io
      repo: rhceph-4-dashboard-rhel8
    rhosp-rhel8:
    - registry: registry.redhat.io
      repo: openstack-zaqar-base
    - registry: registry.redhat.io
      repo: openstack-zaqar-wsgi

Optionally, create a list
  result: "{{ dict(r_keys|zip(r_vals)) |
              dict2items(key_name='org', value_name='repos') }}"

gives
  result:
  - org: rhceph
    repos:
    - registry: registry.redhat.io
      repo: rhceph-4-dashboard-rhel8
  - org: rhosp-rhel8
    repos:
    - registry: registry.redhat.io
      repo: openstack-zaqar-base
    - registry: registry.redhat.io
      repo: openstack-zaqar-wsgi



Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    repolist:
      - org: rhosp-rhel8
        registry: registry.redhat.io
        repo: openstack-zaqar-base
      - org: rhosp-rhel8
        registry: registry.redhat.io
        repo: openstack-zaqar-wsgi
      - org: rhceph
        registry: registry.redhat.io
        repo: rhceph-4-dashboard-rhel8

    result: "{{ dict(repolist|groupby('org')) }}"
    resul2: "{{ dict(repolist|groupby('org')) |
                dict2items(key_name='org', value_name='repos') }}"

    r_groups: "{{ repolist | groupby('org') }}"
    r_keys: "{{ r_groups | map('first') }}"
    r_vals: "{{ r_groups | map('last') | ansible.utils.remove_keys(target=['org']) }}"
    resul3: "{{ dict(r_keys|zip(r_vals)) }}"
    resul4: "{{ dict(r_keys|zip(r_vals)) |
                dict2items(key_name='org', value_name='repos') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: result
    - debug:
        var: resul2
    - debug:
        var: resul3
    - debug:
        var: resul4



Wow! It was so simple!
Many thanks!
